# Calling a JavaScript function that returns a Boolean

Tags: javascript, function, boolean

*** EDITED ***

**REF:** Calling a JavaScript function that returns a Boolean [on hold]

```
function booleanFunction()
{
   if (something) return true;
   else return false;
}
```

My original question was "When calling a Boolean Function, is it correct to say?":

```
if (booleanFunction)
```

or

```
if (booleanFunction())
```

I had previously read that the first choice was correct. Your voluminous responses said otherwise.

Based on all that I have learned from all your responses, I conclude:

(1) `if (booleanFunction)` is truthy in the sense that this if statement will ALWAYS return true. In other words, this if statement is equivalent to asking if this booleanFunction EXISTS, independent of its correctness.

(2) to evaluate the value (true or false) returned by the booleanFunction, I need to say `if (booleanFunction())`.

**Have I concluded correctly?**

Comment: This is still unclear. Why do you think `if (BooleanFunction())` isn't "allowed"? `if (BooleanFunction())` also means something completely different from `if (BooleanFunction)`.

Comment: Where did you read this? This looks like nonsense. A function is always truthy in an `if`. Only its return value is useful here. That’s exactly where you would use `if(BooleanFunction())`.

Comment: The text from "elsewhere" doesn't make much sense to me. I don't understand what they are trying to express. What's your actual question?

Comment: `if (BooleanFunction())` is allowed

Comment: `I am seeing what I think are conflicting answers on calling a JavaScript function that returns a Boolean.` — where?? `except within non-function blocks such as if(). So, if (BooleanFunction()) is not allowed` — what?? where??

Comment: Curious what the question is here.  Curious if you have tried any of the above and if so, why'd you still have a question after?

Comment: I'm legitimately curious now where you  got this information.

Comment: I am actively searching for the source. So far what I do truthfully remember is that my quote came from someone discussing the difference between a expression and a function.

Comment: Unfortunately, whatever was learned here was hoarded and there is nothing left for posterity. The purpose of putting questions on Stack Overflow is so *we all* learn something, not just the OP.

Answer (score 3):

The text you quote is outright incorrect.

To call a function, use parentheses. If the function takes no arguments, the call looks like `booleanFunction()` and returns a value.

To evaluate a value, put it into parentheses. In an if-statement, while-loop, a value is converted to a boolean automatically, the same as `(new Boolean( SOME_VALUE )).valueOf()` or `!! (SOME_VALUE)`. [Refer to MDN for the full conversion rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean). For instance,

```
if (booleanFunction()) {
```

is perfectly fine, but

```
if (booleanFunction) {
```

would convert the value of `booleanFunction` to boolean, and that is `true`, because any function object will be converted to `true`.

Comment: Unless the function reference is falsey for some reason (the last point).

Comment: Is it true then that if(booleanFunction) is truthy in the sense that this if statement will ALWAYS return true? In other words, this if statement is equivalent to asking if this booleanFunction EXISTS?

Comment: And to evaluate the value (true or false) returned by the booleanFunction, I need to say if(booleanFunction())?

Comment: `if (booleanFunction)` will look up the value of the variable `booleanFunction`, whatever that happens to be (for computers, variable names don't matter). In this case, that variable's value is a function, and functions are always true. If there wouldn't be a variable named `booleanFunction`, that would raise a `ReferenceError`.

Comment: Indeed, to call booleanFunction and evaluate its return value, write `if (booleanFunction()) {`. Note that you could also store the value in a variable, for instance `var myResult = booleanFunction(); if(myResult) {`.

Answer (score 0):

I have edited my original question. Hopefully, it is now totally clear.